# Default cargo output directory for binaries

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I downloaded a Rust project and built it with `cargo build`. I have not configured Rust beforehand. Where can I find the output binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'll be under `target/debug` or `target/release` depending on which configuration you built - if the command was just `cargo build`, then `target/debug`.